# Can anyone help me with this double anti-derivative? None of my teachers can...

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

The integral is the following:

$$\iint\sqrt{r^2-x^2-z^2}dxdz$$

Where *r* is a constant and *x* and *y* are both variables.

I have filled pages and pages trying to solve it, i think it can be solved by double trigonometric substitution within a sphere, unfortunately without any results. I have been trying to solve it for a few months now. Thanks!

Comment: I see @Mr.Fry and I have edited this at the same time. In any case, we formatted it for you. Are there limits on the integrals?

Comment: You need some limits on $x$ and $z$.

Comment: Would it be correct to surmise that you're trying to find the volume of a sphere (or hemisphere)?

Comment: Do you absolutely need limits (bounds)? or we can just solve it like an simple anti-derivative? For x i would say -r to r and for z -r to r OR 0 to 2pi

Comment: @ZevChonoles you read my mind... I divided it into infinite cubes and sum up their volumes. This is the 3D version I have a N-D version waiting to be solved (on my own) after this one

Comment: @Investor: It would be much easier to treat it as a volume of revolution by the washer method. That way the square root magically disappears!

Comment: I know, but I'm development my own method and proof of the volume of a sphere. (Investor's method) :P

Comment: You'll need bounds on both your integrals if you want to solve it this way - the bounds on $x$, notably, depend on $z$.

Comment: you mean are functions of x? Thanks for the hint! Can we focus on the anti-derivative then ill work on the bounds.

Comment: First substitute $x$ by $\sqrt{r^2-z^2}\sin\theta$. After you get the first anti-derivative

$$\begin{align}
\int \sqrt{r^2-z^2 - x^2} dx 
&= (r^2-z^2)\int \cos\theta^2 d\theta
= \frac{r^2-z^2}{2}\left(\theta + \sin\theta\cos\theta\right)\\
&= \frac12\left[(r^2-z^2)\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{r^2-z^2}}\right)+ x\sqrt{r^2-z^2-x^2}\right]
\end{align}
$$
you already need to decide what you want to do with the bounds before you can proceed.

Comment: I see... I'll work on it!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are calculating a quantity integrated on a domain which is part of a spherical surface. So you have to describe the shape of the domain (i.e. the bounds of $x$ and $z$) on which you calculate the quantity otherwise it will not make any sense.